# NgRx effect executed only once

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a modal window clicked that when the `Add user` button is clicked it adds the value in the `textbox`, after it does some internal calls like checking the validity of the value in the `textbox`. The `http` calls are executed in an effect, which gets called only for the first entry.

[image]

The problem is that the effect that does the back-end call is executed only once.

The template of the modal:

```
<button class="close" mat-button (click)="closeDialog()">x</button>
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Share with other users</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let principal of data.productList.sharedWith; trackBy: sharedPrincipalsTrackFunction">
    <p>{{principal.uid}} <button (click)="removeUserFromSharedProductList(data.productList.name, principal.uid)">x</button></p>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Share with other users</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.userId">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" mat-button (click)="addUserToProductList(data.productList.name, data.userId)" [disabled]="!data.userId">Add user</button>
</div>
```

Typescript code of the component:

```
  addUserToProductList(productListName: string, userId: string) {
    this.productListService.shareProductList(productListName, userId);
    this.updateDialogData(userId);
  }
```

`productListService.shareProductList`:

```
  shareProductList(productListName: string, userId: string) {
    this._store.dispatch(
      ProductListActions.shareProductListWithUser({
        productListName: productListName,
        userId: userId
      })
    );
  }
```

effect:

```
  shareProductListWithUser$ = createEffect(() =>
    this._actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ProductListActions.shareProductListWithUser),
      mergeMap(action =>
        forkJoin(
          of(action.productListName),
          this._productListOccService.shareProductListWithUser(
            action.productListName,
            action.userId
          )
        )
      ),
      switchMap(([productListName, response]) => [
        ProductListActions.getMyProductLists(),
        ProductListActions.shareProductListWithUserSuccess({
          productListName: productListName,
          principalList: response
        })
      ]),
      catchError((error) => {
        console.log('Acelasi handler de kkt');
        return EMPTY;
      }))})
    )
  );
```

the module file:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature("productListState", productListReducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([ProductListEffects])
  ],
  providers: [ProductListOccService],
  entryComponents: []
})
export class PrtListStoreModule {}
```

I debugged this, but I couldn't understand why the effect is called only once.

Comment: What you need is a reducer `https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers`, ultimately you could try this approach but you'd have to swap `of(action.productListName)` for `withLatestFrom`: `https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom`but you'd still need a reducer and selectors in order to do `withLatestFrom(this.select(selectUser)).pipe( ..do your stuff.. )`.

Comment: @Bargros could this be the cause for my issue?

Comment: If your `catchError` is reached(btw, nice console message ;) ), the entire effect will be unsubscribed, so this should explain why it may happen only once. You can either add a `catchError` after each service call which is subject to errors, or manually re-subscribe to it: `catchError((err, caught$) => caught$)`. As of ngrx 9 you can also provide a custom error handler.

Comment: Damn I jumped the gun with that comment, @AndreiGătej is right but I strongly suggest changing approach here, my apologies for saying this but it doesn't seem like you're fully utilising ngrx, reducers should make managing the state of your app a lot easier and less buggy (not saying your code is but that catchError in your effect does not seem like it should be there tho). I would read about it a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `catchError`, you need to add `repeat` after it to enable the effect again.

```js
      catchError((error) => { // <- closes the stream
        console.log('Acelasi handler de kkt');
        return EMPTY;
      }))}),
      repeat(), // <- resubscribes
```

Ideally would be right to put `catchError` in the `.pipe` of the `.shareProductListWithUser`, then you could avoid `repeat`, but because you have dependencies on the response you can keep the code as it as and to achieve the desired behavior with `repeat`.